# Trying to loop twice but by different amounts for certain variables

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, counter

I have a game where each player (A total of 5 players play the game) has a list of performance attributes. These are listed as arrays below:

`$balance[$i]`,`$marketshare[$i]`,`$price[$i]`,`$unitcost[$i]`

Where `$i` = 0,1,2,3,4. and represents each game player. 
for example `$balance[0]`,`$marketshare[0]`,`$price[0]`,`$unitcost[0]` are
the values for the first player, `$balance[1]`,`$marketshare[1]`,`$price[1]`,`$unitcost[1]`
are the second players values and so on.

`teamID` is the unique id to identify a player.

I have a table that I need to insert this data into using the following SQL.

```
for ($j=0;$j<6;$j++)
{

$value[0] = $profit[$j];
    $value[1] = $marketPercent[$j];
    $value[2] = $saleprice[$j];
    $value[3] = $unitprice[$j];
    $value[4] = "500";
    $value[5] = "600";  

    for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
    {


        $setOutputs = mysql_query("

        INSERT INTO `output`(`outputID`, `outputType`, `outputValue`,`teamID`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$type[$i]', '$value[$i]','$teamID[$j]')

        ") or die($setOutputs."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    }

}
```

The game only has 5 players so I only need the $j in team to loop until it reaches 0 - 5 `$teamID[$j]` currently it runs to 6 and causes an error since there is no data for this player.

How can I modify my code to do this?

Im sure it is simple I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: what is `$value[5] = "600";` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change `$j=0;$j<6;$j++` to `$j=0;$j<5;$j++`.

This will give you 0 to 4 inclusive, which is 5 distinct values - 0 is a value too.

Comment: Yes perfect, thank you. It was such a simple solution, but I got confused trying to follow each loop. If I change the $i to <5 does not work as it excludes the $value[5]. Wow I must have been quite unclear with my question plenty of negative points! :(

Answer (score 2):

You're starting at zero, so change the while part of your for loop to be less than 5.

Iterations of the loop:

```
0 - 1
1 - 2
2 - 3
3 - 4
4 - 5
```

Therefore if it's < 5, the last iteration will be your fifth.

Comment: Yes correct if you meant just the $j loop. Thanks I was quite confused by this simple programming.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i is 0,1,2,3,4, but you're looping up to 5 (i.e. 6 values, including 0)..

change this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
```

to this

```
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
```

also 0-5 is six players, not 5, so if you have 5 teams you want to change this:

```
for ($j=0;$j<6;$j++)
```

to this:

```
for ($j=0;$j<5;$j++)  //i.e. 0,1,2,3,4 == 5 teams
```

Comment: He has a `$value[5] = "600"; `despite what he says about 0-4 :P

Comment: By changing for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++) to for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) will not work as `$value[5] = "600";` does not get inserted to database